# Why the head view width = 0 when using `tableView(UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection: Int) -> UIView` under auto layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using delegate method `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?` to build the head view, and auto layout constraints to layout subviews.

But the console reports constraint issues, and shows the head view `width == 0`.
Below is the code, is anything I forgot that caused the problem?

**The console reports:**

```
    2022-03-04 22:27:14.919256+0800 AMA[85087:3817892] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
        Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
        Try this: 
            (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
            (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000653890 H:|-(16)-[UILabel:0x7fb8c6cff620]   (active, names: '|':_UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView:0x7fb8c6cfe250 )>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006538e0 UILabel:0x7fb8c6cff620.width == 100   (active)>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006539d0 H:[UILabel:0x7fb8c6cff620]-(16)-[UILabel:0x7fb8c6cff900]   (active)>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000653a20 UILabel:0x7fb8c6cff900.width == 56   (active)>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000653a70 H:[UILabel:0x7fb8c6cff900]-(8)-[UILabel:0x7fb8c6cffbe0]   (active)>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000653b10 UILabel:0x7fb8c6cffbe0.width == 0.2*_UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView:0x7fb8c6cfe250.width   (active)>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000653b60 UILabel:0x7fb8ceb04240.trailing == _UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView:0x7fb8c6cfe250.trailing - 16   (active)>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000653bb0 H:[UILabel:0x7fb8c6cffbe0]-(16)-[UILabel:0x7fb8ceb04240]   (active)>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000654000 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView:0x7fb8c6cfe250.width == 0   (active)>" //width == 0, why?
        
    )
    
    Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
    <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000006538e0 UILabel:0x7fb8c6cff620.width == 100   (active)>
```

The last constraint `<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000654000 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UITableViewHeaderFooterContentView:0x7fb8c6cfe250.width == 0   (active)>` shows the headerFooter view width is zero, not the the same width as table view should expected.

**The code in `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` subclass:**

'''

```
class StockRecordTableHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    
    override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        self.layoutViews()
    }
    
    //MARK: -
    private let dateLabel = UILabel()
    private let operationLabel = UILabel()
    private let quantityLabel = UILabel()
    private let valueLabel = UILabel()
    
    private func layoutViews() {
        self.contentView.addSubview(dateLabel)
        self.dateLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(operationLabel)
        self.operationLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(quantityLabel)
        self.quantityLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        self.contentView.addSubview(valueLabel)
        self.valueLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            dateLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            dateLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            dateLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor),
            
            operationLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor),
            operationLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dateLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            operationLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 56),
            
            quantityLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: operationLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
            quantityLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor),
            quantityLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.2),
            
            valueLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            valueLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: quantityLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 16),
            valueLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
}
```

I have checked the layout code many times, but can't find any problem, and what confuse is, when the same layout code used in `UITableViewCell` subclass, then no constraint issues reported.

Is any difference to use constraints for head view?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried your code and it didn't give me any errors. Do you have other constraints? Also, I see you have specific width values for your labels, but maybe you can try using a horizontal stackView as a suggestion

Comment: it's strange what happened. I create a totally new  project, use the same code and structure, and also no constraint bugs report.